# Norm compatibility of ideals and ideles

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L|K$ be a finite separable extension of global fields, $\mathbb{I}$ the idele group and $\mathcal{I}$ the group of fractional ideals. We have a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{I}\to\mathcal{I}$ given by 
$a\mapsto\prod\mathfrak{p}^{v_{\mathfrak{p}}(a)}$. The idele norm between 
$\mathbb{I}_{L}$ and $\mathbb{I}_{K}$ is given by $N_{L|K}(b_{w})=(a_v)$ where each $a_{v}$ is given by $a_{v}:=\prod_{w|v}N_{{L_{w}|K_{v}}}(b_{w})$. The ideal norm is given by $\mathfrak{P}\mapsto \mathfrak{p}^{f(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p})}$ and is extended linearly.

Why is the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{I}_{L} @>>> \mathcal{I}_{L}\\
@V{N_{L|K}}VV @V{N_{L|K}}VV \\
\mathbb{I}_{K} @>>> \mathcal{I}_{L};
\end{CD}
commutative?

Comment: Do you remember the relation between the valuation $v_p$ on $K_p$ and the valuation $v_P$ on $L_P$, when $P$ is a prime of $L$ above a prime $p$ of $K$?

Comment: You mean $v_{P}(t*p)=e(P|p)*v_{p}(t*p)$ for a unit t?
My number theory knowledge is a bit old. Im stuck at showing that $v_{p}(a_{v})=f(P|p)v_{P}(b_{w})$, where $a_{v}$ is defined as above.

Comment: ohh something missing in my comment. Im stuck at showing
$v_{p}(a_{v})=\sum_{P|p}f(P|p)v_{P}(b)$. Main problem is handling the $v_{p}(N_{L_{v_{P}}|K_{v_{p}}}(b_{v_{P}})$.

Comment: You might see my answer below. There is some trouble with the definition of your top arrow, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show the commutativity for an idele $x = (..., 1, \pi_P, 1, ...) \in \mathbb I_L$ where $\pi_P$ is a uniformizer in $L_P$, i.e. $v_P(\pi_P) = 1 / e(P/p)$ (it has minimal postitive valuation — see step 0 just below).
Here $p$ denotes a prime of $K$, and $P$ is a prime of $L$ above $p$.
 It is not difficult to conclude then the commutativity for an arbitrary idele of $L$.

**Step 0.**

Recall first that we define
$$v_P(b_P) := \dfrac{1}{[L_P : K_p]} v_p(N_{L_P/K_p}(b_P))$$
for any $b_P \in L_P^{\times}$, and recall that 
$$[L_P : K_p] = e(P/p) f(P/p).$$

**Step 1.**

We first apply the idele norm to $x$. The only non-trivial component of the idele $N_{L/K}(x) \in \Bbb I_K$ is the component of the prime $p$ :
$$ (N_{L/K}(x))_p = \prod_{Q \mid p} N_{L_Q / K_p}(x_Q) = N_{L_P / K_p}(x_P)$$
because $x_Q = 1$ whenever $Q \neq P$.
We then apply the bottom arrow to $N_{L/K}(x)$, and we get the follwoing ideal of $K$ :
$$ p^{v_p(N_{L_P / K_p}(x_P))} = p^{f(P/p)} $$
Here I used the identites from Step 0.

**Step 2.**

We now follow the other path in the diagram.
First apply the top arrow to our idele $x$. This gives directly $P$.
[Here there is a subtelty : the top arrow is given as follows : for an idele $(b_P)$, we can write $b_P = u_P \pi_P^{n_P}$ for a unique $u_P \in O_{L_P}^{\times}$ and a unique $n_P \in \Bbb Z$, and then this idele is sent to the ideal $\prod_P P^{n_P}$. We have to be careful that $n_P$ is *not* the same as $v_P(b_P)$ in general!]

Apply the ideal norm to this, and you get
$$p^{f(P/p)},$$
which  is exactly what we've found before. That's it!
$\hspace{7cm}\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you!! Now i see where i went wrong. Its basically your step 0 and that $v_{P}(\pi_{P})$ is not 1 :) But found it finally in Neukirchs book. 
So much time wasted for not looking it up instantly.

Comment: @Boki : you're welcome.