Relating the norm $| \cdot |_\mathfrak{p}$ of $K_\mathfrak{p}$ to the norm $| \cdot |_\mathfrak{P}$ of $L_\mathfrak{P}$.
Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields, and $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ a prime, and $\mathfrak{P} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_L$ a prime lying over $\mathfrak{p}$. I'm having some trouble understanding what I think should be a simple question about norms, namely that of relating the norm $| \cdot |_\mathfrak{p}$ of $K_\mathfrak{p}$ to the norm $| \cdot |_\mathfrak{P}$ of $L_\mathfrak{P}$.
Firstly, if we have an element $x \in K_\mathfrak{p}$, how can we relate $|x|_\mathfrak{P}$ and $|x|_\mathfrak{p}$? My approach would be to use that $|x|_\mathfrak{P} = | N_{L/K}(x) |_\mathfrak{p}^{\frac{1}{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]}}$ (from $v_\mathfrak{P}(x) = \frac{1}{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]} v_\mathfrak{p}( N_{L/K}(x) )$), and we have $N_{L/K}(x) = \det(\text{mult}(x)) = x^{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]}$ (as we essentially just get $x$ times the identity matrix which has $[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]$ rows and columns), so we just get that $|x|_\mathfrak{P} = |x|_\mathfrak{p}$.
If the above is true, that intuitively makes sense to me, as the norm of the larger field is supposed to extend the smaller one. However, I'm confused because this seems to break some questions that I've been given to prove (and instead it seems like I want $|x|_\mathfrak{P} = | N_{L/K}(x) |_\mathfrak{p}$ which would also give $|x|_\mathfrak{P} = | x |_\mathfrak{p}^{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]}$ for $x \in K_\mathfrak{p}$). For example, I have the question that for $\mathfrak{N}$ the absolute norm of ideles of $K$, i.e. $\mathfrak{N}(\alpha) = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} |\alpha_\mathfrak{p}|_\mathfrak{p}$, that
$$\mathfrak{N}(i_{L / K}(\alpha)) = \mathfrak{N}(\alpha)^{[L : K]}$$
for all ideles $\alpha \in \mathbb{I}_K$, where $i_{L/K}: \mathbb{I}_K \to \mathbb{I}_L$ is the inclusion map. If I try this I get something like:
$$ \mathfrak{N}(i_{L / K}(\alpha)) = \prod_{\mathfrak{P}} |\alpha_\mathfrak{P}|_\mathfrak{P} = \prod_{\mathfrak{P}} |\alpha_\mathfrak{p}|_\mathfrak{P} \stackrel{?}{=} \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} |\alpha_\mathfrak{p}|_\mathfrak{p}^{[L_\mathfrak{P} :  K_\mathfrak{p}]} = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} |\alpha_\mathfrak{p}|_\mathfrak{p}^{[L :  K]} = \mathfrak{N}(\alpha)^{[L : K]}. $$
If I didn't have the equality I use in the $\stackrel{?}{=}$ (and instead use $|x|_\mathfrak{P} = |x|_\mathfrak{p}$ as I feel it should be), the question wouldn't work. Similarly, I need to prove that
$$ \mathfrak{N}( N_{L / K}(\alpha) )  = \mathfrak{N}(\alpha)$$
for all ideles $\alpha \in \mathbb{I}_L$. However I again get something like
$$ \mathfrak{N}( N_{L / K}(\alpha) ) = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \left| \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} N_{L_\mathfrak{P} /  K_\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_\mathfrak{P})\right|_\mathfrak{p} = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} \left|  N_{L_\mathfrak{P} /  K_\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_\mathfrak{P})\right|_\mathfrak{p} \stackrel{?}{=} \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} \left| \alpha_\mathfrak{P}\right|_\mathfrak{P} = \mathfrak{N}(\alpha),$$
where again I feel instead of the $\stackrel{?}{=}$ I should have $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} \left|  N_{L_\mathfrak{P} /  K_\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_\mathfrak{P})\right|_\mathfrak{p} = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} \left| \alpha_\mathfrak{P}\right|_\mathfrak{P}^{[L_\mathfrak{P} :  K_\mathfrak{p}]}$.
I'm sorry for the very long post, but I'm quite confused! I hope I've given enough context for my confusion, as I feel this is something very simple that I'm being a bit dumb about.

The whole concept of ramification index is basically that $v_{\mathfrak{P}}(x) = e_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}} v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$, if we normalize the valuations. You seem intent to make use of the inertia degree $f_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}} = [L_\mathfrak{P} :  K_\mathfrak{p}]$, but it is rather $e_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}}$ which controls the situation.

Wait that's true, I do remember that ramification equality, but isn't the definition of $v_\mathfrak{P}(x) = \frac{1}{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]} v_\mathfrak{p}( N_{L/K}(x) )$ common as well? As in this outline for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800580/norm-compatibility-of-ideals-and-ideles?noredirect=1
But now I'm also a bit confused at how these things relate together. I feel like these are both true but then I get the ramification equality $v_\mathfrak{P} = e_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$ and also $v_\mathfrak{P} = v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$.

Recall that if $x\in K_{\mathfrak{p}}$, then $N_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}}(x)=x^{[L_{\mathfrak{P}}:K_{\mathfrak{p}}]}$.

Wait but doesn't that give $v_\mathfrak{P}(x) = \frac{1}{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]} v_\mathfrak{p}(x^{[L_\mathfrak{P} : K_\mathfrak{p}]}) = v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$ just using $v(x^n) = nv(x)$ instead of  $v_\mathfrak{P}(x) = e_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$? I think this is why I'm confused, I must be doing something simple wrong here right?

This is just a question of definition, but one has to be careful. Let me start in the global setting, $L/K$ an extension of number fields.
For $\mathfrak{p}\subset K$ a prime ideal, a very natural definition of $\nu_\frak{p}$ is $\nu_{\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha)=\max\lbrace k : \mathfrak{p}^k\text{ divides } (\alpha)\rbrace$. If $\mathfrak{P}\subset L$ is a prime ideal above $\frak{p}$, then it is obvious that for $\alpha\in K\subset L$, $$\nu_{\frak{P}}(\alpha) = e_{\frak{P}\mid p}\:\nu_{\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha).$$
This is neat because the valuations are defined independently in each field, without reference to the extension. However, many authors prefer that the valuation $\nu_\frak{P}$ actually extends $\nu_\frak{p}$, i.e. they agree on $K$. So you a priori decide how $\nu_{\frak{P}}$ should look like on the subset $K\subset L$, but what is a natural description for its values on the rest of $L$? Here, the formula you mentioned saves us:
$$\nu_{\mathfrak{P}}(\beta) := \frac{1}{[L_\mathfrak{P}:K_\frak{p}]}v_{\frak{p}}(N_{L_\mathfrak{P}/K_\frak{p}}(\beta)).$$
This is what Neukirch does. Note that $[L_\mathfrak{P}:K_\mathfrak{p}]=e_{\mathfrak{P}\mid p} f_{\frak{P}\mid p}$, so it relates to some global invariants. Obviously, this valuation could be achieved by taking the first definition and dividing by $e_{\mathfrak{P}\mid p}$. (Note that one can define this valuation without referencing the extension $L/K$, but instead referencing the extension $L/\Bbb{Q}$, so it is independent of the subfield.) One of the reasons to prefer this is that if we define the absolute value as usual, we have nice formulas such as
$$\prod_{\nu} |\alpha|_\nu^{[K_\nu:\Bbb{Q}_\nu]} = 1,$$
When $\nu$ runs over the valuations on $K$. Also note that $\nu$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ is less of an abuse of notation: it is indeed the restriction of $\nu$ on $K$ to the subset $\Bbb{Q}$. This is common in algebraic geometry, for example when defining heights on elliptic curves.
But this definition does indeed imply the equality $\nu_\frak{P} = \nu_\frak{p}$ on $K$, which would give the wrong answer in your computation of the idele norm.
In the adelic setting, it is not uncommon to use a third definition which boils down to the first definition multiplied by $f_{\frak{P}\mid p}$, or
$$\nu_{\mathfrak{P}}(\beta) := v_{\frak{p}}(N_{L_\mathfrak{P}/K_\frak{p}}(\beta)).$$
Now why would we want a third definition, when the first one seems so natural, and the second so useful? Well, the problem is that we want to define the norm on the adeles to be $\prod_\nu |\alpha|_\nu$, but at the same time, we would also like the norm to descend to the quotient $K\backslash\Bbb{A}_K$, where $K$ is embedded diagonally (I am ignoring $0$ here, so a slight abuse of notation). This is equivalent to the norm being identically $1$ on the embedding of $K$, and is exactly what happens with the above definition: this follows from the product formula above, if you compare the two definitions.
So in short, there are many definitions, and you usually pick the one best suited for your setting. The first you mention is not the one usually chosen when dealing with adeles, and to prove your two claims you need to pick the correct one.

Thanks so much! This was an incredible explanation and it really gives the context behind everything, amazing!

Thank you for the kind words. I wanted to add a further remark: some authors prefer keeping the valuation as the first definition, but still want the associated absolute value to have the properties of definition $2$ or $3$. This can be achieved, for example by defining $|\alpha|\mathfrak{p} = p^{-\frac{\nu\frak{p}(\alpha)}{\nu_\mathfrak{p}(p)}}$ to get the product formula I wrote above. But this of course loses the usual connection between the valuation and absolute value, $\nu_{\frak{p}}(\alpha)=-\log_p |\alpha|_\frak{p}$.
So keep an eye out for whichever definitions are at play!
